# UI change when i give much text on EditTExt

Tags: android

This is link of my UI:

[image]

when text is normal.

When i give more text, UI changes like this:

[image: image2]

Below is my xml file code, which change in Ui helps me when enters much text:

Please tell me how can i fix this??

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="1" 
  android:layout_margin="5dp">

   <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/name_lbl"/>
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/nameText" 
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/cap_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/capText"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>

  <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/code_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/codeText"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>




    <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/DoneDate_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Location_lbl"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>
   <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/Notes_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Notes_lbl"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>
   <TableRow>         
     <TextView 
        style="@style/StyleLabel"
        android:text="@string/person_lbl"/>         
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/Person_lbl"
        style="@style/StyleText"/>         
  </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

Below is `styles.xml` :

```
 <resources>    
<style name="StyleLabel">
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
</style>
<style name="StyleText">
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
  <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/textview_border</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below property to your textview.

```
singleLine="false" 
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:lines="1"
```

Comment: @HayyaAnam if you are sure about another textview then just add it in notes textview otherwise add to all textview. Just add above property to your style .

Comment: is not valid again do like same

Answer (score 0):

Place this line in your `TextView` tag of `xml` file:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

then the data entered in `TextView` will be in single line.

***UPDATE:***

Add the below line in all your `TextViews`:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="10" //Restrict to some number of lines
```

Comment: no is a Notes field so is  definately multi line text field   so how i manage its alligment?

Comment: is again did same i give much text on xml like 

 
         <TableRow>         
         <TextView 
             
            style="@style/StyleLabel"
            android:text="@string/Notes_lbl"/>         
         <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/Notes_lbl"
            style="@style/StyleText"
            
            android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="10"

android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
 />         
      </TableRow>

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your styletext

```
android:singleLine="true"
```